# All props and state variables become unresolved variable

Tags: reactjs, redux, webstorm, material-ui

When installing `material-ui/core` by using the following command line:

> npm install @material-ui/core

`Webstorm` throws an

> "Unresolved variable VARIABLE NAME"

error on all `this.state` and `this.props` variables. `Webstorm` also add a small "info-box" next to `render(){` in the component telling me the following:

> implements method in React.Component

When uninstalling `@material-ui/core`, all the errors disappears and everything works again.

What might be the problem?

I'm building a web app using `React` and `Redux`. I created the project with `create-react-app`.

Comment: can't recreate. What WebStorm version do you work with?

Comment: @lena WebStorm 2017.2.4

Comment: it's quite old... I'd suggest updating to the most recent one (2018.1.5)

Comment: @lena it works when updating to 2018.1.5. Very stupid of me for not trying to update before asking here. Thanks for the help!